# Python: how to force Selenium pause at certain actions to mimic humans

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, monkeypatching

[Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) has a lot of actions, e.g., `driver.find_element_by_xpath('XXX').click()`, `driver.find_element_by_xpath('XXX').send_keys()`. I would like to add some features (e.g. random pause) to make them **real (like humans)**.

Adding `time.sleep()` before each action is **not** Pythonic and takes too many lines (one line before an action). In addition, we want the pause time for different types of actions are **different** (`send_keys(input_text)` should be longer than `click()`).

I tried the following but failed:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

def pause_wrapper(func, min_time=0, max_time=None):
    """Before execute func, we pause some time [min_time, max_time]."""
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        pause_time = random.uniform(min_time, max_time)
        print(f'We are going to pause {pause_time} s.')
        time.sleep(pause_time)
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

ActionChains.send_keys = pause_wrapper(ActionChains.send_keys, min_time=5, max_time=10)
ActionChains.click = pause_wrapper(ActionChains.click, min_time=1, max_time=3)

driver.find_element_by_xpath('XXX').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

My questions are:
1. Why my method fails (no pause and no print result)?
2. How to approach it?

---

To clarify: I want to force hard pause, not the other around (as wrongly flagged as similar).

Comment: @DebanjanB This question is WRONGLY flagged as similar to another. I want the hard pause, but the similar question is to avoid hard pause. They are opposite.

Answer (score 2):

you could define a wait like:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
wait = WebDriverWait(driver_instance, 1000)
```

and then use it to perform certain waits like:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait.until(
    EC.url_contains("http://example.com")
)
```

do keep in mind that the wait will throw a `TimeoutException` after a while.

In some cases `time.sleep` is an acceptable solution.

More about the expected conditions can be consulted in [the selenium documentation](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html)

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. But I think it is too troublesome because I have to write codes whenever I need an action. Is there a way to _decorate_ the actions?

Comment: @Tengerye well you could put this in a decorator, I don't see why not.

Comment: My approach in the question somehow failed and I don't know why.

Comment: @Tengerye failed in what way? The code seems to be alright, you are calling `func` after the `time.sleep`.

Comment: It should print out `We are going to pause`, but nothing printed out.

Comment: @Tengerye that's because the `find_element_by_xpath('XXX').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)` doesn't use your decorated `ActionChains.send_keys` method. It uses the one derived from it's DOM element base class. I wouldn't complicate too much and just make a method that waits, and just call that method.